# What accounts does clamav use on different Linux distros

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, fedora, chef, clamav

I'm trying to fix a problem in a Chef recipe for installing / configuring ClamAV which is caused by the recipe using the wrong default user/group name for the clam service account on some platforms.

It seems that:

- On CentOS 6, the service account is "clam"
- On Fedora 19, the service account is "clamupdate"
- On Ubuntu 12.04, the service account is "clamav".

Based on this, I'm guessing that the pattern can be generalized (in Chef terms) to:

- Debian family - "clamav"
- RHEL family - "clam"
- Fedora family - "clamupdate"

Questions:

1. Have I over-simplified this?
2. Does anyone know of any examples that contradict this?  (Lets assume that we are talking about the "recommended" RPMs / DEBs for the respective platforms ...)

Comment: I think you would have to check every distribution individually.

Comment: Well yes, if I had the time to do that I would do that.  (Especially, if there was a way that didn't involve examining a zillion RPMs by hand).  But I'm just hoping that either someone has already done the hard work ... or if someone *just knows* of a case where my pattern is wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you have to check zillion distros by hand. Use the best of your knowledge. If you  or anybody finds it being wrong, it is a small bug and can be fixed. OTOH you might have a look at test-kitchen, which allows you to test large amounts of distros automatically.